# Wire multiple config classes using dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, config

I have working configuration class in spring. I tried to replace hard-coded string by configuration map using dependency injection.

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class BwlConfiguration {

    @Resource(name="loadParameters")
    private Map<ConfigEnum, String> conf;

    private String address;

    public BwlConfiguration() {
        address = conf.get(SPI_BL);
    }
...
}
```

Class that provides conf map:

```
@Configuration
@Component
public class ConfigLoader {

    @Resource(name="returnEnv")
    private Map<String, String> env;

    @Bean
    public Map<ConfigEnum, String> loadParameters() throws ParameterNotSetException{
        ....
        return parameterMap;
    }
```

Class that provides env map:

```
@Configuration
public class EnvConf {


    @Bean
    public Map<String, String> returnEnv(){
        return System.getenv();
    }   
}
```

When I run the program, nullPointerException is thrown at `address = conf.get(SPI_BL);` line. I tried to replace `@Component` by `@Import(...class)`, same result and it's losing the point of injection. 
Am I using these annotations wrong? Thanks

Comment: Where did you replace `@Component` by `@Import`; in `BwlConfiguration`, or in `ConfigLoader` and `EnvConf`? Don't remove `@Component` from any of the classes. Add `@Import({ConfigLoader.class, EnvConf.class})` to `BwlConfiguration`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, however the result is the same, still NullPointer.

Comment: @Jesper why do you need `@Component` on `@Configuration` ?

Comment: @DeendayalGarg My mistake, you actually don't need a `@Component` annotation on `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @Wlad what does the rest of your code look like? The most common reason for an exception like this is if you manually create a new instance of a class yourself (doing `new BwlConfiguration();` somewhere) instead of letting Spring manage it.

Comment: Remove `@Component` from `@Configuration` classes and I have a feeling things will start working.

Comment: I found the error. Mistake was that I used and assigned values retrieved via injection in constructor of Configuration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced constructor in `BwlConfiguration`  with:

```
@Bean
public String address(){
    return conf.get(SPI_BL);
}
```